How to click on any non-button elements on a web page using Selenium & Python
I'm trying to scrape search results from google maps. However once I enter my search, the results come up in a portion of the frame with a scroll bar not a part of the entire body. I need to click on a consistently appearing text (such as "Results") after my search is entered to activate the part of the website where the scroll bar is so I can send by down keys to automatically scroll down.
def search_industry_and_scroll(driver, industry):
    driver.get('https://www.google.com/maps')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'searchboxinput')))
    search_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'searchboxinput')
    search_input.send_keys(industry)
    search_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.Nv2PK.THOPZb')))

    # Click on the div element after the search
    div_to_click = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.vasquette.id-app-container'))
    )
    div_to_click.click()
    
    # Scroll down the page
    body = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body')
    while True:
        body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
        time.sleep(2)  # Wait for new elements to load


you may try to use JavaScript to click element - something like this driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', element). You may also use execute_script to run some more complex code which can search elements with document.querySelector() - like driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("button div.class_name").click()')
